# NSView performance of wantsLayer

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, appkit

If I create a blank Mac XCode project and layout 500 simple `NSView` objects side by side in the main window it loads pretty damn fast.  If I set `wantsLayer=YES` on each subview, performance dramatically drops, by several seconds.  Why is this the case conceptually?  It seems that layers would be faster not slower than regular old NSViews.

Comment: Instruments should tell you :/

Comment: Good idea and I took a look and couldn't decipher anything.  I mean I know it runs really slow and I was I hoping to find something in the call stack to indicate why but couldn't.  I was wondering if anybody knew the answer conceptually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're giving the system more work to do by layer-backing so many views. Layer-backing allows graphic acceleration (for drawing) but it adds a bit of overhead to things like layout, not to mention *just creating them and putting them on screen*. If used properly, it's not really much of a problem.

Typically, if you had so many "things" to manage on screen at once, you'd have one layer-backed hosting view that manages its own tree of sublayers. "But what about view-based table views?" you ask. Trickery, *trickery*, I say! Table views don't actually keep all the cell views they manage around; they efficiently reuse them, keeping around only enough to represent what's on screen and/or animating around.

So I'd say this isn't really a problem since it's not a particularly good approach to throw 500+ layer-backed views up for layout and drawing to begin with. :-)

Comment: This isn't an approach I am considering, it's just one I am trying to understand.   You nailed it.  Somebody here at work explained the same this morning.   Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

as of 2021, Joshua Nozzi's answer is just the half of the truth.

When you want to utilise that much layers, you should make use of the power of CALayers with Sublayers instead of using NSViews over and over again, each with its own NSCell and possible CALayer backed as you forced it to with `-wantsLayer:`.

There is nothing wrong with 500 sublayers. Sublayers allow you to be fast when properly structured.

If you want to speed up even more, **turn off autoanimation** by force on each Layer that does not need it. Yes a lot examples out there show that you can turn off Autoanimation each time you call some property to be changed, slowing down your drawing even more, because it involves even more object messaging.

Keep in mind the following example turns off Auto-animated Keys by their Key name and kicks out the whole action and does not apply onto all Sublayers on purpose. If your structure of Sublayers of Sublayers need it you could call this on according ParentLayer to wipe out the CPU eating Autoanimation. Its much better to let the autoanimation do its job on the layers you actually want it to. *Which turns around Apples default paradigm to animate everything.* If most action keys are turned off be aware that your layers do show up kind of like a state machine. In the example here `@"frame"` animations are not wiped out..

```objectivec
void turnOffAutoAnimationsForLayerAndSublayers(CALayer* layer) {
    NSNull *no = [NSNull null]; //(id)kCFNull
    NSDictionary *dict =  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[no,no,no,no,no,no,no,no]
                   forKeys:@[@"bounds",@"position",@"contents",@"hidden",@"backgroundColor",@"foregroundColor",@"borderWidth",@"borderColor"]];
    for (CALayer *layertochange in layer.sublayers ) {
        if (layertochange.sublayers.count) {
            for (CALayer *sublayertochange in layertochange.sublayers) {
                sublayertochange.actions = dict;
            }
        }
        layertochange.actions = dict;
    }
}
```

and use it in your `CALayer` backed `NSView` **-init** like..

```objectivec
CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
layer.frame = self.frame;
//...backgroundColor, contents, etc etc..

// here you could even do a for loop adding as much sublayers you want..  
for (int y=0; y<100; y++) {
    CALayer *sub = [CALayer layer];
    //...frame, backgroundColor, contents, of sublayers etc etc..
    layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, y*10);
    [layer addSublayer:sub];
}
// structure is ready, add it to the base layer
self.layer = layer;
// now tell NSView you really want to make use this layer structure
self.wantsLayer = YES;
// turn off AutoAnimations
turnOffAutoAnimationsForLayerAndSublayers(self.layer);
```

For layers that are basically all the same there is even a specialised Subclass called `CAReplicatorLayer`. Allowing you to add even more with less internal draw calls.

You should also know that layers that are **hidden** *are not calculated at all* (meaning drawing here). You can still change properties even on hidden Layers. Unhide them, when needed, not earlier. So in example a custom `CATextLayer` that will change its **string** property to lets say `@""`, aka nothing, will still be drawn. But if you Subclass CATextLayer and change its string implementation to lets say..

```objectivec
@interface YourTextAutoHideLayer : CATextLayer
-(void)setString:(id _Nullable )string;
@end

@implementation YourTextAutoHideLayer
-(void)setString:(id _Nullable)string {
    self.hidden = [string isEqual:@""];
    super.string = string;
}
@end
```

you speed up drawing even more. A) because less object messaging to hide the layer that has no text anyway and B) once hidden it is not part of the internal draw calls effective speeding up your main CALayers drawing.

On NSTableViews that are NSCell based you usually never use CALayers. There is no need to, NSTableViews manage the visible Cells on purpose to keep in example scrolling smoothly. And still they (NSTableViewCells) have a reuse-mechanism to speed things up. You will very likely not re-invent a tableview with CALayers anyway. But in case you do reinvent, there is a CAScrollLayer class too.

And if that is not enough speed it is worth thinking about a MetalView utilising the power of GPUs.

Edit: code your CALayers not in `-drawRect:`. `-drawRect:` is called anytime something changes, in example frame/position on screen or bounds etc.. so try to avoid coding CALayers in there. You can set `[self setNeedsLayout:YES];` & `[self setNeedsDisplay:YES];` on purpose for a good reason, the reason is you want to avoid too much drawing for basically no change at all. `-drawRect:` in example was/is such method that is supposed to handle a backing with its own context to draw in. As CALayers have their very own mechanism you can  let the drawRect block blank, doing nothing in there, maybe even erasing the method at all if you dont need it.

CALayers are not part of the auto layout system unless you code in `-layout..` so again, keep CALayer drawing outside such and you are good. and pssst a lot CALayers properties can be changed even outside the main thread, some definitely not like `layer.string`.